# How to print function into different files in c programming

Tags: c, function, printing

I have defined the following function in the header region,

```
void printArray(float list[]){        /* function decleration for printing array elements */
    int iii;
    for (iii = 0; iii < length;iii++){
        printf("%lf\n", list[iii]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

To print this I just write  `printArray(x);` where I have an array `x[iii]=iii;`

Throughout the code I want to print this into different files. So early on I want this to print to `FILE *File_First_Array_Printing;` with an "initialised variables" text file, while later I want it to print to `FILE *File_Fourth_Array_Printing;` with a "final variables" text file.

Normally when I print into files I would do something like this,

```
File_First_Array_Printing=fopen("Initialised-variables.txt","w");

                  fprintf(File_First_Array_Printing,"initialised array x: %f\n",printArray(x));
                                                                       /* printing the initialised arrays */
                  fclose(File_First_Array_Printing);
```

But it doesn't seem to like that! Please could you advise?

Comment: `printArray` doesn't return anything but the `%f` format string means that `printf` will expect a float value. You need to define `printArray` so that it returns the output or takes a `FILE` as a parameter and writes to it.

Comment: Do not define functions in headers, only declare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the `FILE *` to your `printArray` function and use that inside of the function to call `fprintf`:

```
void printArray(FILE *fp, float list[]){ 
    int iii;
    for (iii = 0; iii < length;iii++){
        fprintf(fp, "%lf\n", list[iii]);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
File_First_Array_Printing=fopen("Initialised-variables.txt","w");
if (!File_First_Array_Printing) {
    perror("open of Initialised-variables.txt failed");
} else {
    printArray(File_First_Array_Printing, x);
    fclose(File_First_Array_Printing);
}
```

Comment: I was wondering how I can modify the general function to also print the variable associated to the array? e.g how to attach the variable 'x' to the print out? Given that there will not just be x but also y, z etc ...Your help would be very much appreciated!! :)